# second order ODE :- solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

We have $y''-Py'-Qy = 0 $ where P,Q  are     $P = K_1+K_2x, Q =K_2 $.

$K_1,K_2$ are constants. y' means derivative with respect to  x . Please suggest a solution for y. Thanks

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27-%28k1%2Bk2*x%29y%27-k2*y+%3D+0)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I tried all the methods in  these  links 1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsoW0lXrg9g 2) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdIJ1XmR0Pc 3) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI475pM-qqE  .. None worked out

Comment: Alpha doest give steps